# Magento 2.1 Mini cart is not working knockout.js error

Tags: mini-cart, magento-2.1

2.0.7 was working fine with all browsers but after upgrade to 2.1 the store is not working, bought items not adding to the cart so customer cannot checkout. even with fresh installation the cart is not functioning properly. please see herara.com.

browser inspection showing :
knockout.js:2908 Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Comment: What theme are you using and do you have any customer extensions?

Comment: luma.. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5554